# How to measure time of mounted widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple `StopWatchController` which i want to use to measure the time it takes to to `mount` `SecondPage` when clicking on the button `next page` in `MyHomePage`. I am not sure how i can achieve a succesfull return of the time between clicking and mounting. The return is always the start time when i `debugPrint`. How can i achieve a succesfull `stopWatch.elapsed`?

full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StopWatchController {
  var stopWatch = Stopwatch();

  stopWatchHandler(timer) {
    if (timer == "start") {
      stopWatch.start();
    } else if (timer == "stop") {
      stopWatch.stop();
      debugPrint(stopWatch.elapsed.toString());
      return stopWatch.elapsed.toString();
    }
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
           child: Text("next page"),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.of(context)
              .push(
                 MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        const SecondPage()));
            StopWatchController().stopWatchHandler("start");
          }
           
        )
      ),
      
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const SecondPage({
    Key? key,
    
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  initState(){
    if (this.mounted == true) {
      StopWatchController().stopWatchHandler("stop");
    }
    super.initState();

  }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child:  Text("")
      ),
      
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit**

It `debugPrint`: `0:00:00.000000` when i press on `next page`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `stopWatchHandler(timer)` function

```
stopWatchHandler(timer) {
    if (timer == "start") {
      stopWatch.start();
    } else if (timer == "stop") {
      stopWatch.stop();
      debugPrint(stopWatch.elapsed.inMilliseconds.toString());
      return "executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed.inMilliseconds}ms"; //<=== change-here
    }
  }
```

Comment: No it still `debugPrints`: `0:00:00.000000`

Comment: please check updated answer. check in debugPrint.